# How to apply a external layout from my web project A into my web project B (asp net core)?

Tags: asp.net-core, layout, view, partial-views

I have two web projects with the same layout.
The project A is the Layout project and the project B will be a application project.

I wish to consume the project A as a Nuget package to project B. This way the layout maintenance of future projects will be in only project A. In projects B or C be enough apply the latest version of Nuget package.

I don't know how to do it...

I tried using Iframe, but it didn't work, because i need to render my project B in @renderBody of Project A

I tried to point the link of localHost Project A in the viewStart of Project B
and... didn't work...

Answer (score 0):

Use a Razor Class Library. You put all your common resources there: views, layouts, tag helpers, view components, even static files, and then reference them in your other projects.

It's similar to a regular ASP.NET Core project, except there's no `Program` or `Startup`, because it doesn't run on its own. However, you can add controllers, views, Razor Pages, etc. just the same.

For more information, see the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/ui-class?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio).